# Else statement being executed in custom shortcode

Tags: php, html, if-statement, shortcode, wpbakery

I have the following shortcode mapped to display a dropdown field in WPBakery:

```
array(
    'type' => 'dropdown',
    'heading' => esc_html__( 'Type of container', 'js_composer' ),
    'param_name' => 'container_type',
    'value' => array(
        'Container' => 'container',
        'Container fluid (full width)' => 'container-fluid',
    ),
    'std' => 'container',
    'description' => esc_html__( 'Select whether you want the content to be contained or full width on the screen.', 'js_composer' ),
)
```

It is being initialised in another file where its attributes and markup is defined:

```html
<?php

/**
 * Shortcode attributes
 * @var $container_type
 */

class vcRow extends WPBakeryShortCode {

    function __construct() {
     add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'vc_row_mapping' ) );
     add_shortcode( 'vc_row', array( $this, 'vc_row' ) );
    }
    
    public function vc_text_mapping() {
     vc_map(
            array(
            'name' => __('row', 'text-domain'),
            'base' => 'vc_row', 
            'description' => __('', 'text-domain'), 
            'params' => array(
                array(
           'type' => 'dropdown',
           'heading' => esc_html__( 'Type of container', 'js_composer' ),
           'param_name' => 'container_type',
           'value' => array(
                     'Container' => 'container',
                     'Container fluid (full width)' => 'container-fluid',
                    ),
                    'std' => 'container',
          ),
            );
    }

    public function vc_row($atts, $content) {
     extract(
            shortcode_atts(
                array(
                    'container_type'  => '',
                ),
                $atts
            )
        );
          
        if ($container_type == "container-fluid"){
            echo "container-fluid";
        } else {
            echo "container";
        }
    
        echo "<p>".$container_type."</p>";
    }
   
}

new vcRow();?>
```

One of my fields is set to 'container-fluid`, but an`echo`of`$container_type` is showing "container" (meaning the else statement is being executed. Unsure why?

Comment: As you explained it is not possible. You must be sure the $container_type is never != of "container-fluid". Try this: echo "{$container_type} - container-fluid"; and echo "{$container_type} - container";

Comment: Have you tried dumping $container_type before hand to see it's value ?

Comment: @DylanKas - Yup, it returns `string(0) ""`. But, unsure on why its return is false?

Comment: Well if that's the case ""  is not equal to "container-fluid" so you need to look into why your $container_type variable is equal to "" instead of what you want

Comment: Where is the variable defined ?

Comment: @DylanKas It's defined in the same file: `public function vc_row($atts, $content) { extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'container_type' => '', ), $atts ) );`

Comment: Can you edit your post and show how you set a value to $container_type

Comment: @DylanKas - Sure, I've updated the question

Comment: You wrote  'container_type'  => '', is it normal ? It doesn't look surprising that $container_type is equal to ''

Comment: @DylanKas - `container_type` is the `param name`. Its value has to be empty since it's based on what's selected from the dropdown, right?